# R RODBC sqlSave in table with Auto Incrementing Column

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I am having a table "Table1" in a database with the columns AiID and Name,
where AiID is the primary key and an auto-incrementing integer and Name any character.

When I want to use `sqlSave`:

```
df <- data.frame(AiID = as.integer(NA), Name = as.character("Test"))
sqlSave(channel, dat = df, tablename = "dbo.Table1", append = T, rownames = F, fast = F, test = F)
```

I get the error:
"Error in sqlSave(channel, dat = df, : unable to append to table ‘dbo.Table1’"

My feeling is that it has to do with the auto-incrementing AiID, but how would I deal with that in R/RODBC, when I want to insert new rows?

The channel itself is working, as I can update existing entries.

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer for the error is your column definition of AiID. If it is function generated in SQL, it may not let you input any given value. This happened to me ONLY when I defined a function generated column as Primary Key. 
I was able to append my values by copying the PK column values into a new column, defining the new column as a PK and generating PK values from R. In my case it was a concatenation of columns, in your case the autoincremental. 
RODBC don't let you write a subset of columns (as far as I know).